# Run code on http context before or after spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I'd like to run some code (for logging, or custom security, etc) before and/or after spring calls the controller method. I know `Filter`s can be created to operate on `ServletRequest`s and `ServletResponse`s, but it's not clear how to access headers, body, query parameters, etc from those.

Most similar to what I'm trying to do is action composition in Play Framework for java.

Is there a way to do this in Spring?

Comment: Take a look at [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to inject a Header for every request using a Filter

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public final class VersionFilter implements Filter  {

@Value("${version}")
protected String version;

protected FilterConfig filterConfig;

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse responseAddition = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    responseAddition.addHeader("X-Application-Version", this.version);

    chain.doFilter(request,responseAddition);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
}
```